# Program has errors, binary operators

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
class InsurancePolicy
{
    friend fstream&  operator<<(fstream&, InsurancePolicy);
    friend istream& operator>>(istream&, InsurancePolicy&);
private:
    int policyNum;
    string lastName;
    int value;
    int premium;
};
fstream& operator<<(fstream& out, const InsurancePolicy pol)
{
    out << pol.policyNum << " " << pol.lastName << " " << pol.value << " " << pol.premium << endl;
    return out;
}
istream& operator>>(istream& in, InsurancePolicy& pol)
{
    in >> pol.policyNum >> pol.lastName >> pol.value >> pol.premium;
    return in;
}
int main() {
    ofstream outFile;
    outFile.open("Policy.txt");
    InsurancePolicy aPolicy[10];
    for (int count = 0; count < 10; ++count)
    {   
        printf("Enter the policy number, the holder's last name, the value, and the premium.");
        cin >> aPolicy[count];
        outFile << aPolicy[count] << endl;
    }
    return 0;

}
```

This program will not compile because of the following errors:
Severity
Code
Description
Project
File
Line
Suppression State
Error
C2679
binary '>>': no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'std::string' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
Project6
c:\users\preston freeman\source\repos\jave.cpp
21

Error
C2679
binary '<<': no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'const std::string' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
Project6
c:\users\preston freeman\source\repos\jave.cpp
16

Error
C2679
binary '<<': no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'InsurancePolicy' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
Project6
c:\users\preston freeman\source\repos\jave.cpp
32

How do I fix these errors?
Thank you for your time.

Comment: The conventional overload is on `ostream`, not `fstream`. And check your function prototypes one more time.

Answer (score 0):

You are using

```
ofstream outFile;
```

in main. 
But your operator overloading is

```
 friend fstream&  operator<<(fstream&, InsurancePolicy);
```

Note that `ofstream` is not derived from `fstream`, that's why overloading `operator <<` for  `fstream` won't make it work for `ofstream`

You can simply change `fstream` to `ofstream`

```
ofstream& operator<<(ofstream& out, const InsurancePolicy pol)
{
    out << pol.policyNum << " " << pol.lastName << " " << pol.value << " " << pol.premium << endl;
    return out;
}
```

And better to pass in InsurancePolicy by const& since ofstream won't change it, and copy a user defined object can be expensive

```
ofstream& operator<<(ofstream& out, const InsurancePolicy& pol)
```

You may also need to `#include <string>`

Demo:
https://ideone.com/rJiw21

Comment: Looks like you are using visual studio, so you may also need to #include <string>

Comment: File
Line
Suppression State
Error
LNK2019
unresolved external symbol "class std::basic_ofstream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > & __cdecl operator<<(class std::basic_ofstream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > &,class InsurancePolicy &)" (??6@YAAAV?$basic_ofstream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@AAV01@AAVInsurancePolicy@@@Z) referenced in function _main
Project6
c:\Users\preston freeman\source\repos\Project6\Project6\jave.obj
1

Error
LNK1120
1 unresolved externals
Project6
c:\Users\preston freeman\source\repos\Project6\Debug\Project6.exe
1

Comment: See this demo, https://ideone.com/rJiw21, and it compiles fine. Are your sure the declaration and definition of the function have the exact same signatures?